# Java - Click JButton to change value of int to a random number between specific range

Tags: java, random, indexing, scope, captcha

I am working on a project that involves creating a captcha.

I have an array of captcha images:

```
Image[] CAPTCHAimageArray = {2G4QH, 4FTD2, 7BJHL, etc.};
```

I also have an array of captcha strings:

```
String[] CAPTCHAstringArray = {"2G4QH", "4FTD2", "7BJHL", etc.};
```

I want to generate an index int that would, in effect, randomly select a captcha image and its corresponding string.  Seems simple enough - I created this bit of code thinking I was on the right path:

```
Random rn = new Random();
int i = rn.nextInt(46);
```

So far so good.  I created a JLabel that displays the captcha image:

```
JLabel lblCAPTCHA = new JLabel("");
lblCAPTCHA.setBounds(162, 152, 300, 180);
panelCAPTCHA.add(lblCAPTCHA);
lblCAPTCHA.setIcon(new ImageIcon(CAPTCHAimageArray[i]));
```

Finally, I added a JTextfield where the user would input their interpretation of the captcha.  The user clicks a JButton, and I *am able* to compare the user's input with the captcha string properly... but only once!

The problem is that I am unable to change the value of this int i:

```
int i = rn.nextInt(46);
```

I try to change its value to a newly generated number (i = rn.nextInt(46);) within the ActionListener section of the submit button, but I get the error "local variable defined in an enclosing scope".  I am unable to change the original int i to a new random number.  I *was* able to get around this in a very shoddy manner, which is by adding this bit of code to the end of the ActionListener:

```
int i = rn.nextInt(46);
lblCAPTCHA.setIcon(new ImageIcon(CAPTCHAimageArray[i]));
```

This is only able to change the image to a new captcha image, but the index still focuses on the original captcha string.  Basically, the program is only able to focus on the first captcha string.  I'm unable to change the value of the original int i.

Whats the best way to go about solving this?

If you'd like to see the entire section of code involving the captcha, here it is:

```
    /* CAPTCHA MENU CONTENTS */

        //"Account Creation" Text
            JLabel lblAccountCreation_3 = new JLabel("Account Creation");
            lblAccountCreation_3.setBounds(263, 89, 109, 16);
            panelCAPTCHA.add(lblAccountCreation_3);

        //"Please input the above message:" Text
            JLabel lblInputMessage = new JLabel("Please input the above message:");
            lblInputMessage.setBounds(207, 383, 209, 16);
            panelCAPTCHA.add(lblInputMessage);

        //Initiate CAPSLOCK Filter
            DocumentFilter filter = new UppercaseDocumentFilter();

        //CAPTCHA TextField
            CAPTCHAtextField = new JTextField();
            CAPTCHAtextField.setBounds(258, 411, 130, 26);
            panelCAPTCHA.add(CAPTCHAtextField);
            ((AbstractDocument) CAPTCHAtextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);

        //CAPTCHA Image Array
            Image[] CAPTCHAimageArray = {c2G4QH, c4FTD2, c7BJHL, c7JDFV, c9PB43, c9TVB4, cADVE8, cAZQRV,
                    cBLTFT, cBYF4D, cD8URH, cDBVFX, cDQAXC, cECD6A, cERTYA, cGTJRD, cGY67E, cHDP7R,
                    cJU4RV, cK8CRW, cKJPHL, cKMFDM, cL9MBP, cLGU3W, cLKMDR, cLMRTD, cLMUFX, cLPDT2,
                    cLPTY2, cLXF49, cMKNLH, cMY62A, cPT7W2, cRDAVH, cRTLPQ, cRVBAZ, cT7TMW, cUL4B7,
                    cUW2CZ, cVBCHY, cVF4TU, cW36X9, cWX2DT, cYT782, cYWRQZ, cZKGF8};

        //CAPTCHA String Array
            String[] CAPTCHAstringArray = {"2G4QH", "4FTD2", "7BJHL", "7JDFV", "9PB43", "9TVB4", "ADVE8", "AZQRV",
                    "BLTFT", "BYF4D", "D8URH", "DBVFX", "DQAXC", "ECD6A", "ERTYA", "GTJRD", "GY67E", "HDP7R",
                    "JU4RV", "K8CRW", "KJPHL", "KMFDM", "L9MBP", "LGU3W", "LKMDR", "LMRTD", "LMUFX", "LPDT2",
                    "LPTY2", "LXF49", "MKNLH", "MY62A", "PT7W2", "RDAVH", "RTLPQ", "RVBAZ", "T7TMW", "UL4B7",
                    "UW2CZ", "VBCHY", "VF4TU", "W36X9", "WX2DT", "YT782", "YWRQZ", "ZKGF8"};

        //CAPTCHA Image Generation
            Random rn = new Random();
            int i = rn.nextInt(46);
            JLabel lblCAPTCHA = new JLabel("");
            lblCAPTCHA.setBounds(162, 152, 300, 180);
            panelCAPTCHA.add(lblCAPTCHA);
            lblCAPTCHA.setIcon(new ImageIcon(CAPTCHAimageArray[i]));

        //"Submit" Button
            JButton btnSubmit_4 = new JButton("Submit");
            btnSubmit_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String CAPTCHAinput = CAPTCHAtextField.getText();
                    //Check if input matches CAPTCHA
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 46; ++j) {
                        if (i == j) {
                            String CAPTCHA = CAPTCHAstringArray[i];
                        //System.out is to see which captcha the program is focusing on
                            System.out.println("i = " + i);
                            System.out.println("CAPTCHA is " + CAPTCHA);
                            if (compareCAPTCHA (CAPTCHA, CAPTCHAinput)) {
                                panelEmail.setVisible(true);
                                panelCAPTCHA.setVisible(false);
                                CAPTCHAtextField.setText("");
                                int i = rn.nextInt(46);
                                lblCAPTCHA.setIcon(new ImageIcon(CAPTCHAimageArray[i]));
                            }
                            else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error - CAPTCHA input incorrect!");
                                CAPTCHAtextField.setText("");
                                int i = rn.nextInt(46);
                                lblCAPTCHA.setIcon(new ImageIcon(CAPTCHAimageArray[i]));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            btnSubmit_4.setBounds(260, 463, 117, 29);
            panelCAPTCHA.add(btnSubmit_4);

        //"New CAPTCHA" BUTTON
            JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New CAPTCHA");
            btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int i = rn.nextInt(46);
                    lblCAPTCHA.setIcon(new ImageIcon(CAPTCHAimageArray[i]));
                }
            });
            btnNewButton.setBounds(255, 504, 130, 29);
            panelCAPTCHA.add(btnNewButton);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a god-class, a class with too much responsibility and unnecessary complexity, and for that, consider refactoring that code with an eye towards simplifying and distributing responsibility to smaller grained classes. A M-V-C or Model-View-Controller based program structure would be a good start.

As for your main problem, how access `i` from within your inner class, make the array index an instance field of the class that it resides in, not a method or constructor-local variable.

Other issues: I would create a class to hold the image and its String together as a single logical unit, I'd consider using ImageIcons and not images so that I can easily swap the icons in and out of JLabels. I'd avoid null layouts and `setBounds(...)`. Also note that ImageIcons can hold both an image and a String, the String for its "description"` complete with getters and setters. You could just use items of this class and use the description String for the captcha String result.

Comment: I got it running how it should work!  I figured out how instance fields work and it worked out exactly how I'd like it to.  Thanks for your response.  I'm also going to look into fixing the code and "break it up" into smaller more manageable sections.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your random number in another method, and call that method when you click on the button. This is the easiest way to get the desired effect.